# UITextView not scrolling when created programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I am creating UITextView programmatically.

```
content = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: header.frame.origin.y + header.frame.size.height, width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height - viewTop.frame.size.height))
content.font = UIFont.init(name: "OpenSans", size: 17)
content.textColor = UIColor.black
content.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
content.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
content.isScrollEnabled = true
content.isEditable = true
content.isSelectable = true
content.bounces = true
content.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true  
self.addSubview(content)
```

It is not scrolling though.

Comment: Just write => content.text = "Hello World!"

Comment: Is there any text in your text View

Comment: @HabibAli : No text. It is for input purpose.

Comment: then it will not scroll untill you put some long text in it

Comment: @HabibAli : I did put very long text, still didn't scroll.

Comment: hmm thats creapy.

Answer (score 0):

TextView will scroll only when the Content Size is greater then the textView's frame. So on setting the textView's text with enough text should allow it to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like that the code for adding the textview is probably in the `viewDidLoad` method. When you add any view in `viewDidLoad` method there are good chance that the view will not have proper frame and content size. Also there are good chance that any other view can ovelap on that. You can check by debuging the view by clicking the [image] image in debug area.

If the above scenario is right then you can fix the problem by putting `content.bringSubview(toFront: self.view)` in `viewDidApear` method.

Answer (score 0):

You have added the content view to it self. Change this to view and it will scroll.

```
view.addSubview(content)
```